# Android instrumentation tests, choice of libraries. Should I use libs:test:testing-support or test:rules or test:runner?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

On official website:
https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/index.html

they say, that I have to add this:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

but in tutorials I found:

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.3'
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
```

Which libraries do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my latest project I'm using these `androidTest` dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.6.2'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_VERSION"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
```

Beware that some tutorials might be really out of date. Notice that I'm using `com.android.support.test` subLibrary at its latest version `0.5`, not `0.3`.

Also, beware that `rules` and `runner` are have diferrent contents, so you may use both, but one instead of another

I'm also pretty sure that Google's tutorial about `Espresso` is enough and you don't need to use others. Check: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/

Hope it will help